# Comparison of Metric Spaces and Completeness

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Yesterday I had a discussion in which I presented a proof that a particular metric space is not complete. On this space $X$ there are two metrics $d$ and $d'$, with respect to $d'$ it is not complete, but with respect to $d$ it is, furthermore $d(x,y) \le d'(x,y)$ holds. It was noted that using this inequality the proof that it is not complete is very simple, but I don't know how to use this, this just implies that ever sequence w.r.t. $d'$ is also convergent with respect to $d$ and every Cauchy-sequence in $(X,d')$ is also Cauchy in $(X,d)$, but I don't see how to infere from that the incompleteness of $(X,d')$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly cannot make such an inference: it’s consistent with the inequality that $d\,'=d$. You can’t make such an inference even if you assume that $d(x,y)<d\,'(x,y)$ whenever $x\ne y$: it’s consistent that there is $d(x,y)=\alpha d\,'(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$, where $0<\alpha<1$, in which case $\langle X,d\,'\rangle$ is complete iff $\langle X,d\rangle$ is complete.